# Bold text in pdf

Tags: pdf, bold, texmaker

I use a TexMaker for creation of my report. But when I look the created pdf-file, there is no bold text.
How to fix this?

```
\bfseries{Lorem ipsum dolor} \textit{sit amet}, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
```

[logs](http://www.filedropper.com/6_3)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{extreport} 

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[warn]{mathtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,mathtext,cite,enumerate,float, mathtext} 
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %pdftex
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[format=hang, figurename=Малюнак, tablename=Табліца , labelfont=bf,tableposition=top, labelsep=space, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}  
\usepackage{titlesec}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.} 
\makeatother

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{left=3cm}
\geometry{right=1.5cm}
\geometry{top=2cm}
\geometry{bottom=2cm}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}% 
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}% 
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{.\arabic{enumii}}% 
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.}% 
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{.\arabic{enumiii}}% 
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.}% 



\addto\captionsrussian{
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {\centerline{ЗМЕСТ\vspace{14pt}}}%
  \renewcommand{\bibname}
    {\centerline{СПІС ВЫКАРЫСТАНЫХ КРЫНІЦ}}  
}


\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing


\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{ddd}{ -- }
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=ddd, justification=raggedright, font=normalsize, margin={-0.0cm, 0pt},
position=top}
\captionsetup[tabularx]{labelsep=ddd, justification=raggedright, font=normalsize, margin={-0.0cm, 0pt},
position=top}
\captionsetup[longtable]{labelsep=ddd, justification=raggedright, font=normalsize , margin={-0.0cm, 0cm},
position=top} 
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=centering,labelsep=ddd, font=normalsize}

\makeatletter

\setlength\LTleft{0cm}      



\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}


\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fontencoding{T1}
\fontfamily{times-ttf}
\fontseries{m}
\fontshape{it}
\fontsize{14}{15}
\selectfont


\titleformat{\chapter}{}{\thechapter}{14pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}{}{\thesection}{14pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{}{\thesubsection}{14pt}{}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{17pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{17pt}{17pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{17pt}{17pt}

\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}


\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$-$}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}


\setlist{leftmargin=3.0em}

\makeatletter
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1} 
\makeatother

\fontfamily{times-ttf}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Did you use the command `\textbf` or `\bfseries`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel yes, of course

Comment: Where does `\fontfamily{times-ttf}` come from? It's highly non standard.

Comment: It is used for font-family set Times New Roman. I removed it, but all the same the text in pdf didn't change.

Comment: I think there is a problem with how you are loading fonts, especially as combined with your `\usepackage[T2A]{fontencoding}` command.  But it is hard to know because I have no idea what 'times-ttf' is (is it on Windows)?

Comment: @jon I use GNU/Linux Ubuntu. I removed rows with 'times-ttf'

Comment: Do you receive any warnings in your `.log` file?

Comment: @Werner added the file [link](http://www.filedropper.com/6_3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snippet isn't very useful. I tried the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\bfseries{Lorem ipsum dolor} \textit{sit amet}, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\end{document}
```

Which results in
[image]

Please note the command `\bfseries` has no argument. `\bfseries` will set the whole text in bold until the current group is closed. On the other hand the command `\textbf` has an mandatory argument. The command `\textbf` will print the mandatory argument in bold.

---

I looked to your log file. I think you should do this too. There are lots of warnings. One of them is:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/ptm/bx/it' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/ptm/bx/n' instead on input line 1.
```

That means the combination with the encoding `T2A` the font family `ptm` (Times) with the series `bx` (bold extended) and the font shape `it` (itshape) isn't available. So you have to use a font which can use such a combination.

Comment: but i need _extreport_ class

Comment: @mark: that makes no difference

Comment: @mark: The my update.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I'm wondering: Is this question _too localized_, or should it be renamed to something along the lines of _bold in ptm's T2A encoding doesn't work_ (which essentially seems to be the problem) and the MWE trimmed down a lot? Someone googling "bold text in pdf" probably won't find the kind of information here that they're looking for. (Hence, it probably should be renamed either way.)

Comment: @doncherry: I think this question need the headline -- I can't understand the warning XY. -- to localized with the current header will be the correct choice.